# How to center some text and right-align more text on same line?

Tags: css

I'm surprised that this has been so difficult for me.  I need a single line with some text centered and the rest right-justified:

```
                          Centered Text                         Right Text
```

I doubt this matters, but "Centered Text" needs to be a `<div>` or `<span>` since I need to manipulate its content with jQuery.  "Right Text" needs to be a `<div>` so I can apply styles to links it contains.

I've tried to `float: left` things, but I can't get it working.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far.  I've tried out some, and can get them to work in isolation.  My problem is that I'm trying to do this in a larger document filled with CSS I didn't write.  The area I'm writing to is enclosed in several containers, each with 'float' properties.  Perhaps this is causing my problem.  My eyes are blurry, so I'll come back to this later with a fresh mind.

Answer (score 7):

```
<div style="float: right">Right Text</div>
<div style="text-align: center">Centered Text</div>
```

The key is putting the floating element first.

Comment: Centered Text displaced by Right Text, see answer @michael-la-voie http://stackoverflow.com/a/1549073/908936

Answer (score 4):

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div style="background-color: #EEEEEE;">
            <div style="float: right;">Right Text</div>
            <div style="width: 100px; margin: 0 auto;">
                Centered Text
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need a container `div` with `text-align: center`, and within it a `div` with `float:right`:

```
<div style='text-align: center'>
<div style='float:right'>Right Text</div>
Centered text
</div>
```

You can wrap `Centered text` in a `<span>`, should you need to.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="float: left; width: 65%; text-align: center">
    centered
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 35%; text-align: justify">
    justified
</div>
```

Hope this helps